# unable to change name strategy in Doctrine 2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am using Zend Framework 2.4.3 and Doctrine 0.9(For ZF2). My entity names are in CamelCase whereas my table names are all in lowercase. It results as error on mysql

> "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mydb.Campaign' doesn't exist"

Of course I can rename my entity to lowercase but my question is 
why Table annotation is not working I have defined my entity as

```php
/**
 * ORM\Table(name="campaign")
**/
class Campaign
{
    //fields are here
}
```

I created a `custom NamingStrategy` to lowercase the table name but Doctrine somehow is not using `NamingStrategy`. I am saying this because I have changed the code of `DefaultNamingStrategy` to change the table name case but resulted table name is always Campaign and not "campaign".

Am I missing something?

Comment: MySql and there is no way for me to change it from case sensitive to case insensitive

Comment: Why is this question tagged "symfony2"?

Comment: You are including the ORM namespace in your entity file?

Comment: Yup I am including ORM namespace "use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM"

Comment: @FrancescoAbeni because symphony2 is also downloaded as dependency. I am newbie and don't know whether it relates to symphony or not

Answer (score 0):

If this code is that that you use for yout entity, then thera is a missing `@` before `ORM`:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="campaign")
 */
class Campaign
```